# loading arcore in unity gives weird error

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm trying to load ARCore with unity but I keep getting this error. Anybody know what's causing it.

> Error building Player: TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'UnityEngine.XR.Tango.NativeImage' from assembly 'UnityEngine,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: What version of Unity are you using? Is it 2017.2b11 or f1?